# Keep Alive in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Any potential issues with enabling keep alive in the .htaccess file for my Drupal 7 websites?
 Header set Connection keep-alive

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any potential issue with using `Keep-Alive` unless it is not properly configured. e.g

1. `​KeepAliveTimeout` value is not ideal. For example, if the site is high traffic the value should be higher​ to make sure there is no frequent tcp connection re-initiated.
2. ​`MaxKeepAliveRequests` should be tweak according to number of assets the server is serving.

It is recommended to use this feature to:

1. Reduce latency
2. Reduce the use of server resources such as CPU and memory

For HTTPS you might want to check SPDY.

> ​SPDY is a protocol developed by Google to increase the speed and
>   efficiency of delivering web content. SPDY modifies parts of the
>   HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) to improve web performance.